# PHP Mailer gives out Error as "Page not working"

Tags: php, phpmailer

I m trying to make PHP Mailer work for my website, I have added the PHP mailer folder in my hosting in that websites folder, and added the code for mail. And when i run it, it gives an out put as "Page Not Working".

```
    <?php 

  require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port=587;
  $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
  $mail->Username='harishkolliparat@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password='12345';

  $mail->setForm('harishkolliparat@gmail.com');
  $mail->addAddress('harishkolliparat@gmail.com');
  $mail->addReplyTo('harishkolliparat@gmail.com');

  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject='Form Submission: Subject';
  $mail->Body='<h1 align=center>Name : Harish';

  if(!$mail->send()){
      $result="Some error";
  } else {
      $result="Thanks";
  }

?>
```

Any Help or Suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest reading [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) if you haven't

Comment: So, is the error "Error Occurred While Processing” or "Error Prepossessing"?

Comment: @kerbholz its Please try Later, Error Occured while Processing..."..

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example has "A Simple Example" using try/catch, Debugging and $mail->ErrorInfo. You might want to use that approach to see what goes wrong